# Login using codeigniter without alert error messages

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Can Anyone give me a simple CodeIgniter example?

When the login fails, "Unable to login" message as alert. Error message will print near to the text boxes. Anybody can help?

Comment: Hope it will help you... :)

Answer (score 0):

> You can use flash message for that.

**Define it in your controller when you check login:**

```
$this->session->set_flashdata('loginfail', 'Incorrect username or Password');
redirect('loginpage');
```

**In your view page:**

```
$this->session->flashdata('loginfail'); //write this line where you want to display message.
```

Let me know if any query....!